# Who are these two of Thor's love interests (blue-haired "swashbuckling Passionista" woman and "wolf woman") and where are they from?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, thor-marvel, thor-love-and-thunder

In *Thor: Love and Thunder*, Korg narrates that Thor had two love interests aside from Jane Foster: a blue-haired (pirate?) woman (described by Korg as a "swashbuckling Passionista") who Thor kisses while on a wooden (pirate?) ship (as shown in the teaser trailer), and a "wolf woman" who Thor kisses while on a large wolf ("a woman wolf"). Who are they (including the large wolf)? And from what worlds are they from? Are they also characters and worlds from the comics?

[image: blue-haired Pirate "swashbuckling" woman][image: blue-haired Pirate "swashbuckling" woman]
[image: Wolf Woman][image: Wolf Woman]

Comment: I may be wrong but I don’t think there’s any significance to either character.

Comment: The only significance I see at present is the vague allusions to his sister Hella - Thor needing to come to an accommodation with his past.

Comment: Fenris’s sister maybe?

Answer (score 10):

Elsa Pataky (AKA Mrs Chris Hemsworth) is identified in the [credits](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10648342/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_cl_sm) as '*Wolf Woman*' and Zia Kelly (AKA Natalie Portman's stunt double) is credited as '*Pirate Woman*'.

It doesn't seem like they're anything other than a one note joke, especially since the two characters don't have names, just descriptions of their roles.